# How does systeminfo print lines?

Tags: c, windows, cmd, printf

I am using below code to get systeminfo on Windows 7.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    FILE *p;
    p = popen("systeminfo", "r");

    if(!p) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening pipe.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while(!feof(p)) {
        printf("%c", fgetc(p));
    }

    if (pclose(p) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr," Error!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When the code is run, command line waits for a few seconds to get the required information. The first line says:

```
loading processor information...
```

then updates itself as:

```
loading hotfix information...
```

This happens 5 or 6 times more and then actual output is written in command line window.

I want to ask how this first line update itself although the code says to print all characters sequentially?

```
printf("%c", fgetc(p));
```

Comment: The only thing you can retrieve is what is actually output  by *systeminfo*, and only in the order it outputs it. Run *systeminfo* from a command prompt and view the output as it runs.

Comment: Thanks. But it does not print line by line. It prints the second sentence by deleting the previous one. Is not it against printf logical?

Comment: Not sure to understand the question, `\r' allow to override the current line

Comment: `\r' seems to move the cursor to the beginning of line. But some sentences are not equal. How do they delete the remnant characters?

Comment: I used `if(fgetc(p)=='\r') continue;` in `while` loop to force printing line after another but it did not have any effect. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you actually asking how to print status information on a single line? with systeminfo just as an example? This is about cursor control and terminal emulation in that case.

Comment: Instead of `printf`, capture the output of `systeminfo` and dump it to a binary file. Then examine that.

Comment: @kdopen according to what I read, printf supposed to print characters without moving cursor position. my code behaved differently so I wanted to ask the mechanism behind it. it seems '\r' character moves the cursor position but there is no '\r' character in systeminfo output apparently. I am still not sure how the output is generated. How can I print raw characters of systeminfo output to CMD window so that I can watch how Windows regulates the information on CMD window?

Comment: `printf` prints characters. If printing those characters happens to have the side effect of moving the cursor position, then the cursor will move. Also, don't use `feof()` to control the termination of your loop. Check the value returned by `fgetc()` (`EOF` if no more input is available).

Comment: Thanks. But there is no '\r' so how systeminfo moves the cursor to the beginning of the line?

Comment: Systeminfo output does not contain that `Loading Bla Bla` lines. Proof: try `systeminfo /fo list>nul` from command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some experimentation, and it turns out that if standard output is redirected, `systeminfo` sends the status lines to standard error instead.  (If both standard output and standard error are redirected, the status lines are suppressed.)

Since `popen` only redirects standard output, your code isn't seeing the characters in the status lines, they're going to the console via standard error.

(Note that it is also possible for a child process to ignore redirection altogether and send its output directly to the console.)

Comment: Here's what I see in the debugger. If either `stdout` or `stderr` is a console, then `sysinfo!PrintProgressMsg` is called with a valid console handle and directly calls `SetConsoleCursorPosition` and `WriteConsoleW` to print the progress message. Similarly the final print by `sysinfo!ShowMessage` calls `WriteConsoleW` for console output. Otherwise it prints to the stdout stream via `fprintf`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I also want to ask how to differentiate the status line (ProgressMsg) with actual output (Message). Because cursor position handled by Windows dynamically, how can C code detect whether a new status line redirected or actual message written on console?

Comment: @Jessie, why are you interested in the progress messages? Since they're written directly to the console you'd have to read them directly from the console screen buffer, which assumes you're attached to the same console window. Generally I prefer to run utilities such as this as [detached processes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684863#DETACHED_PROCESS), in which case it won't even have a console window to print the progress.

Comment: I am thinking that it maybe useful to redirect whole status lines and message to a file for debugging in case a non-console project requires such an implementation. For easy reading I thought I can add new line characters by myself for progress message while writing to file, if there is a way to differentiate progress message and actual message.

Comment: @Jessie: most command-line applications don't behave this way, usually the output goes to either standard output or standard error so you can capture it.  The `systeminfo` command is one of the exceptions, there really isn't any good way to capture the progress lines.

Comment: @Thanks Harry. Much helped.