# C#: process.OutputDataReceived is not always triggered

Tags: c#, process, console, output, stdout

I made the following simple example which should capture all the output and send it to my server where it is just decoded back to string (C# server) and wrote to console using `Console.WriteLine()`:

```
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C " + command;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => {
    if(e.Data == null)
        return;
    var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(e.Data);
    client.Send(bytes, bytes.Length);
};
process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.WaitForExit();
```

To test this stuff, as command I used `systeminfo` which displays what is currently doing on the first line (probably using `\r`) and then displays all the data over multiple lines. I tested the `systeminfo` in CMD. The event is trigerred just when all data appears, which means some seconds (when just the first console line is written) I get nothing. Basically, I don't have any way to see on the server what's happening.

How can I capture literally everything? I also managed to use `process.ErrorDataReceived` with its redirect activated. I didn't got anymore the lines on the client console (the right lines appeared in the console, but the event wasn't triggered), but the trigger is still not called. What I did wrong?

**EDIT (due possible duplicate):**

I changed the code in order to make use of `StandardOutput`:

```
process.Start();
Task.Run(() => {
    var buf = new char[256];
    int readed;
    while(! process.HasExited) {
        readed = process.StandardOutput.Read(buf, 0, 256);
        var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(buf, 0, readed);
        client.Send(bytes, bytes.Length);
    }
});
```

The same behavior happens, the code reaches the `bytes` declaration within `while` when the command is writing normal lines, but while it is writing on the first line, nothing happens. Tested it with `StandardError` too.

**EDIT (what's happening on the server):**

```
while(true)
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(server.Receive(ref client)));
```

In everything above I set breakpoints on the `.Send()` so I know what the client is sending.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Process output redirection on a single console line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716580/process-output-redirection-on-a-single-console-line)

Comment: Regarding your edit: Could you post the relevant part of the receiving code?

Comment: @JanWichelmann U mean all stuff around the second block related to the first block?

Comment: ? I meant the part of your server, which receives and outputs the respective bytes.

Comment: Alright, I think I've got it, check this out: [How does systeminfo print lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29475333/8528014) - Looks like your code is correct now, but the command you are testing with is actually doing weird things. It will probably be easier to just write a simple own test program.